# How to make links to dynamic content work from outside a GWT page

Tags: ajax, gwt, hyperlink

I have a webapp `example.com` written in pure GWT. Obviously the webapp
has dynamic links, like `example.com/#/link1`.

I want  `example.com/#/link1` to be accesible from outside my website. For example. I would like to post the `example.com/#/link1` link in facebook.com so my friends can see it. However, when someone clicks on the link, it will take him to `example.com`, NOT `example.com/#/link1`, even though I have a valueChangeHandler in my EntryPoint.

So my question is, how to make dynamic links accesible from outside my GWT page.

EDIT: found out answer:

In EntryPoint do the following

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
     String initState = History.getToken(); 
    //This is your initial token for your gwt ap
    System.out.println(initState);

    //Do any stuff you want to here, like init some stuff in your app, and finally:
    History.newItem(initState);
    //That las line calls the initial state of your app. This worked for me because I
    //changed the history state in between, so I had to save initialState, do stuff and then
    //fire inistial state.
}
```

Comment: Great work editing in the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you need to work with Activities and Places to handle browser history. This creates a link between a place/state/page in your application and the URL in the browser by inserting/parsing URL place tokens. Have a look at the content of this Google Dev [page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).

You should be able to do what you want with [history](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) handling. You define a set of tokens which describe places/pages/whatever state in your application. Your app parses tokens in the URL and redirects to the appropriate page/view.

Comment: I read the Google dev link but It doesnt answer my question. What I need is a way for links to my site, coming from external, sites to work.

Comment: See the extra link I added. I still think this is the way to proceed - you can encode application state/view as a parsable token and then parse it to determine which dynamic link to display.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I figured it out 10 mins ago. I just needed to use History.getToken() and History.fireCurrentHistoryToken()

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! If you have a small code sample it would be  cool to update your question with the solution you used so it may be useful to anyone that stumbles upon this in the future.